# How to prevent Visual Studio from reformatting my resource (*.rc) file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mfc

I am currently maintaining an MFC C++ project with a legacy version in Visual Studio 6 and an updated version that we've converted to work with visual Studio 2010.  Feature/bug changes in one version or the other are being merged via SVN to the other.

A problem we're having is that one or the other versions of VS is reformatting the .rc file which means during some merges the diff makes it look like almost every line of the file has changed.

Is there a way to turn off or control how this auto-formatting of the resource file so that it is changed only in places where there are real changes?

Comment: Probably ye olde tab vs space debacle.

Comment: Not really, no. Visual Studio manages the resource file itself when you use the resource editor. It's not designed to be edited by hand, so changes are not preserved. If you don't want it to be subject to regeneration by the tool, then don't use the tool. The resource editor is an optional component; you can just open the RC file directly in VS's text editor.